# cert-manager can use DNS-01 challenge on GKE, with "xip.io" domain?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

I tried to get tls using cert-manager DNS-01 challenge on GKE.

So far, I don't have any domain so I want to use xip.op,
DNS zone : test
DNname: 111.222.333.444.xip.io

and I have record set, like  `web.111.222.333.444.xip.ip` whose A record data is "111.222.333.444"

Then adding Issuer & Certificate on GKE, but checking challenge,

> $ kubectl describe challenge
> Error presenting challenge: No matching GoogleCloud domain found for domain xip.io.

We cannot use DNS-01 validation to xip.io domain ?
Because of firewall rule, I need to use DNS-01 instead of HTTP-01.

I beg someone's help

Answer (score 2):

No, that won't work. For DNS-01 you need to use a real domain, that you control (and can create DNS entries under). For it to work with cert-manager you additionally need to have the DNS managed by [one of cert-manager's supported DNS providers](https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/dns01/#supported-dns01-providers) (Google Cloud DNS being perhaps the easiest choice if you're using GKE, but not the only one).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I actually used CloudDNS, added managed_zone, which DNS name is "111.222.333.444.xip.io" .
Understood that I need to have my-own domain to use DNS-01

Comment: @Ryo yeah, it doesn't work to add a managed zone for a zone that you don't actually manage :)